# make row wrap in foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I wanna make 4 column wrap a `.row` container, below is what I tried but there is a row in last not what I want..  How to remove the last row  make it correct

```
<div class="article-list-container">
  <?php $column_count = 1; ?>
  <div class="row">

  <?php foreach ($data_select_top_hits['article'] as $each_data_select_top_hits) { ?>
    <div class="article-list">
      <!-- .. -->
    </div>

      <?php if (($column_count % 4) == 0) { ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <?php } ?>
      <?php $column_count++;?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

output

```
<div class="article-list-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="article-list"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Adding the rows into arrays and then going through that array and wrapping the rows.

```
<?php
$column_count = 1; 
foreach ($data_select_top_hits['article'] as $each_data_select_top_hits) { 
$row_chunk.="<div class='article-list'>$each_data_select_top_hits</div>"; 
if (($column_count % 4) == 0) { 
$chunk_array[]=$row_chunk;
$row_chunk="";
} 
$column_count++;
} 
?>
<div class="article-list-container">
<?php foreach($chunk_array as $rows){ ?>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $rows; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```